# How to click/tap on content drawn using core graphics in appium for iOS

Tags: ios, selenium, core-graphics, appium

I am new to Appium and use it for iOS native app automation.

Appium version : 1.2.0
Webdriver : Selenium
Testing framework : JUnit
Programming language : Java

I have an iOS application where the contents are drawn using Core Graphics. I need to click/tap on certain content(word) using Appium with the co-ordinates specified.
My question is, how can I tap on the content drawn using CG? 
For example, how can I click on "Start" using Appium using co-ordinates where the origin is `x=0`, `y=102` and size is `height=305`, `width=320`. 
The content is present within this and must be scrolled for other contents.

I tried with .tap, .press of TouchAction(). The test case passed but it has not clicked.

Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question makes a lot of sense. Things drawn with CG aren't elements, and there's not a lot of documentation on how to do manual taps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general gist of what you need to do to tap something. (My attempt at a Java translation of my python code)

```
WebElement application = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]"))
Action action = TouchAction(driver)
action.tap(application, x, y, 1).perform()
```

When testing drawing/tapping code, I like to point it at a sample drawing app like [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html) and that lets me see exactly what's going on.